# Show a minimized form when another is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I go about showing a form that was previously minimized when another form is closed or hidden, without instantiating another form.

```
private Form1 mainForm = null;
public Admin(Form callingForm)
{
   mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Hide();
   this.mainForm.BringToFront();
}
```

Why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Hide();
   this.mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this before the BringToFront()

```
this.mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```